# Singleton connection + singleton prepared statement

Tags: java, mysql, performance, jdbc, singleton

I am implementing a server with MySQL server.

I have come to a conclusion that all my queries will be sent using prepared statements.

I am going to make multiple singleton prepared statements for different purposes(For example, select token, insert/replace token, insert phone numbers ...).

Here are my questions.

1. For singleton prepared statements to perform well, should I close it every time I execute a query? (close only the ResultSet, not prepared statements or the connection)
2. Will singleton prepared statement be better than creating a statement every time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple answer - **create and close statement every time**.

If you are not implementing a VERY specialized batch functionality, then creating and closing prepared statement will be an insignificant overhead.

Also having a singleton connection is not a good idea for server application. Only a single thread can work with one connection at any time.

Comment: This depends on the the JDBC driver being used and whether a connection pool is in use. If neither the driver nor the pool is caching the statements then you will lose the benefit of prepared statements.